# Server Error using @RequestMapping to get .jsp to Load

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, request-mapping

I am trying to reference a new .jsp in my WEB-INF/pages folder, but continue to get a server error (specifically 500). I am new to Spring so am unsure exactly where my problem is so I have provided pieces of the code below and can provide more details if needed.

My ViewResolver is:

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
   <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
   <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean 
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                    <property name="viewClass"
                              value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
   </bean>
```

while my Controller is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/nav")
public class NavigationController {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NavigationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private NavigationService navigationService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView home() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        modelAndView.addObject("testimonials", navigationService.getTop5Testimonials());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newpage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("about2");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

My Dispatcher Servlet is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mazefire.controller"/>
</beans>
```

and the web.xml is

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         version="3.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>MazeFire</display-name>
    <description>MazeFire Digital Maze Games</description>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/nav/home.do</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MazeFireDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Things worked fine referencing the homepage (index.jsp) using

```
<a href="<c:url value="/nav/home.do"/>"
```

but when I try to reference the new page (about2.jsp) the website doesn't load and I get the error.

```
<a href="<c:url value="/nav/page/about2.do"/>"
```

I feel the problem is in the syntax for /page request, but would appreciate any help in figuring out what is wrong. If any other information is needed, please let me know.

**Update:** Logs show:

```
27-Jul-2017 11:13:51.283 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
27-Jul-2017 11:13:56.603 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
27-Jul-2017 11:15:25.121 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MazeFireDispatcher'
27-Jul-2017 11:16:46.653 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
27-Jul-2017 11:16:46.654 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [MazeFireDispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception
 java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
27-Jul-2017 11:16:46.695 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(8)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
27-Jul-2017 11:16:49.653 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(8)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
27-Jul-2017 11:16:54.980 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(8)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
27-Jul-2017 11:18:18.151 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(8)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MazeFireDispatcher'
27-Jul-2017 11:19:39.991 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(8)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
27-Jul-2017 11:19:39.991 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(8)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [MazeFireDispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception
27-Jul-2017 11:19:42.718 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MazeFireDispatcher'
27-Jul-2017 11:21:01.341 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
27-Jul-2017 11:21:01.341 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [MazeFireDispatcher]
27-Jul-2017 11:21:01.342 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'MazeFireDispatcher'
27-Jul-2017 11:22:23.009 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
27-Jul-2017 11:22:23.009 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [MazeFireDispatcher]
```

Comment: try `/nav/page.do`, the URL maps to a method not to the location of the file

Comment: Thanks @tima but it is now loading an internal error page instead of the about2.jsp even though the URL is referencing correctly as (http://mazepilot.com/nav/about.do). I am building off someone else's code and most other pages are using the GET method with RequestParam so not sure if there are conflicts with what I am trying to add as mentioned in my post.

Comment: i'm not sure what the problem is but `/nav/page.do` should be the correct URL. Maybe check the logs to see why the internal error page shows up.

Comment: I've added the logs running a local environment using Tomcat on IntelliJ IDEA. Unfortunately I'm too new to be able to make sense of them and am not 100% sure if the errors shown here match with whatever error is happening on the live website (sort of figuring all of this out on the fly). I have the detailed logs saved as PDF's if helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 500 because of Communications link failure between your data base and your application

```
 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
    27-Jul-2017 11:16:46.654 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup Servlet [MazeFireDispatcher] in web application [] threw load() exception
     java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Make sure that your application have network access to your database (and the firewall isn't blocking ports to your database).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql) is some helpful info about it.